# Как добавить/удалить атрибут у input?

Tags: jquery, toggle

Есть задача: по клику на кнопке добавлять/удалять атрибут у инпута. Пробовал делать так:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#input").toggle(
    function() {
      $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  );
})
```

Однако, toggle только скрывает и открывает инпут, ничего никуда не добавляет.

Почитал, что toggle устарел. Какая есть альтернатива?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.
>   http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('#input').prop('disabled', function( i, currentValue ) {
        return !currentValue;
    });
});
```

[Интерактивный пример](https://jsfiddle.net/alexey_m_ukolov/w5r7h26e/)

Обратите внимание, что метод .prop() оперирует напрямую DOM-элементом, не обновляя разметку, в отличие от метода .attr(). Поэтому он работает быстрее и рекомендуется к использованию, но в остальном коде вам тоже нужно будет использовать именно его, а не .attr(), чтобы оперировать актуальными значениями.

Comment: Короче `$('#input').prop('disabled', (i,v) => !v);`

Answer (score 1):

Не особо понял в чём смысл кода, но на поставленную задачу ответил бы вот так:

```
$("#button").on('click', function(e){
  var val = $('#input').attr('disabled');
  $('#input').attr('disabled', !val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
  if($("#input").prop('disabled')) {
    $("#input").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#input").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```